# how to add a char* into char** in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array of char arrays in C (not C++). The type is char**. I know it's length, but the lengths of the elements are unknown.
and I have another char* array.
Need to append this char* to my char**, as the last element.

Comment: Knowing its *length* is half the knowledge you need. You also need to know how many elements are **occupied**. if they're one in the same, you're have no place to put your incoming `char *` without a resize. If they're not, then put it in `ar[last++]`, where `last` is the current number of occupied slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> char* arr1[]; //known length with some already filled elements

each element of the above array is a pointer to  character array.

> char *new = "lastElem" // this is the string you have to append

let us say, arr1 has n elements(each a string). Then,

> arr1[++n] = new; // this should do it, provided space exists in arr1 and you already have the          //character array 'new'.

Comment: is arr1 empty or is arr1 itself NULL?

Comment: It's not NULL. I've allocated it with
arr1=(char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));

Comment: try this: char **arr1; arr1 = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*4);//to store 4 strings. arr1[0] = "hello"; arr1[1] = "world"; char *c = "!!!"; arr[2] =c;

Comment: when I try to output arr1 I get "helloworld". then it stops with error of reading memory. That's probably because I add in one procedure, and try to read in another, those have different scope. my main() calls that module(). Appending is in module, but I want it's result in main.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
char **pointers;
char *p;
/* ... */
pointers[last] = p;
```

The one thing you need to get right is the value of `last` and you can easily keep track of it as you add elements to `pointers`.

#### EDIT

A simple way to keep track of `last` is to always say:

```
pointers[last++] = p;
```

Another way is to keep a copy and advance it:

```
char **pts = pointers;
/* .. */
pts = p;
pts++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy with `realloc`:

```
char **array = ...;
array = realloc(array, sizeof(char*)*(LENGTH+1));
array[LENGTH] = last;
```

(I'm assuming you need to increase the size of `array`, otherwise `array[LENGTH-1] = last` is enough)

Comment: Thanks,but this doesn't work. that was the first what I've tried. Debugger says bad pointer. and if add several elements in cycle the array only keeps first added element

Comment: res= (char**) realloc (res, sizeof(sum)*(r_len+1)*sizeof(char));
res[r_len]=sum; 
r_len++;

sum is char*, which's generated before.